# textbox displays wrong color

Tags: ms-access, textbox

I have a bug:

My Microsoft Access report has a textbox that is supposed to have a black forecolor but displays pink instead.

The code setting the forecolor to black is reached and The forecolor is set to black but when the report is finished the textbox displays a pink number.

There are no other references to the textbox in my code.

The default textbox forecolor is `#7F7F7F` which is grey.

Further the same code correctly sets other textboxes to a black forecolor.

I have cross-checked properties between the text boxes and they all are the same.

What could I be missing?

This is the function call to set the textbox:

`SetPointsTextBox frmWeeklyMotivationSystemReport2.Controls!txtSaturday3, status`

```vb
Sub SetPointsTextBox(textbox As Control, status As clsStatus2)
  If status.DisplayTodaysPoints = 0 And status.DayEvent > 0 Then
    textbox = DisplayEventasString(status.DayEvent)
    textbox.ForeColor = vbBlue
  Else
    textbox = status.DisplayTodaysPoints
    If status.status = 4 Then
      If status.DisplayTodaysPoints > 0 Then
        textbox.ForeColor = vbRed
      Else
        If status.DisplayTodaysPoints = 0 Then
          textbox = "" 
        Else
          textbox = 0 
          textbox.ForeColor = RGB(205, 155, 29)
        End If
      End If
    Else
      If status.DisplayTodaysPoints < 0 Then
        textbox.ForeColor = vbRed
      ElseIf status.status = 2 Or status.status = 9 Then
        textbox.ForeColor = vbBlue
      Else
        textbox.ForeColor = vbBlack 'code gets to here and changes the forecolor to 0
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an issue that we can replicate. Perhaps you should delete and recreate textbox.

Comment: deleting and recreating the control worked.  thank you.  too bad I can't mark a comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

deleting and recreating the control worked.  thanks for the helpful suggestion.